# Обособление сравнительного оборота в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Лысина профессора сверкала как солнце". Будет ли здесь запятая? Я подразумеваю, что да, но решила все-таки спросить у вас.

Answer (score 1):

**Лысина профессора сверкАла, как сОлнце.**

Это сравнительный оборот, структура предложения позволяет его обособить.

**Примеры:**

Солнце играло на небе, и золотые кудри молодого короля сияли, **как солнце.** [Л. А. Чарская. Дуль-Дуль, король без сердца (1912)]

...она, проходя мимо, едва приметно кивнула ему головой. **Он просиял, как солнце…**  [М. Ю. Лермонтов. Герой нашего времени (1839-1841)]

В некоторых случаях при логическом выделении оборота он может не обособляться:

На бале, говорят, **как сОлнце** вы блистали. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]

Comment: Платье ее горит и сверкает, как солнце. [Е. Л. Шварц. Золушка (1946)]

Comment: Оборот обособлен, а что здесь не так?

Comment: Все так. В дополнение к ответу привожу пример со сверканием, ведь в вопросе лысина именно сверкает, а не сияет.